# Replace letters in a word with a character

Tags: mit-scratch

I need to replace certain letters in a word with a character.

I'm stuck. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you already have most of the code. You just need to add the letters that don't need to be replaced and are not in the `consonants` list.

To do this, I would use an `if-else` instead of an `if` in your loop. This will allow you to replace letters that are in the `consonants` list and add letters that don't need to be replaced to the `final word`.
It would look something like this: [image: new scratch code]

Note that the `consonants` list has the characters that are to be replaced in word `word`.

This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank ypu very much